# Checkbox inside container with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="toggle-bar">
    <h3><input type="checkbox" class="select-all"> Title</h3>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

When I click the `.toggle-bar`, a `toggle()` will be triggered for `.content`. But how can I prevent the `toggle()` if I check the checkbox?

I tried the following but didn't work for me:

```
$(".toggle-bar").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".content").toggle();
}).children(".select-all").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `stopPropagation` in child elements click event to prevent parent click.

```
$(".select-all").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  //
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I also tried it in the parent element click function. But didn't work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the event and stop its propagation using `stopPropagation()`

```js
$(".toggle-bar").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".content").toggle();
});
$(".select-all").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-bar">
  <h3><input type="checkbox" class="select-all"> Title</h3>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the event target element class name is "select-all", and if so return void.

You would change your code to look like this...

```
<div id="toggle-bar" class="toggle-bar">
    <h3><input type="checkbox" class="select-all"> Title</h3>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript to look like this...

```
$(".toggle-bar").click(function(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (target.className === 'select-all') {
        return;
    }

    $(this).next(".content").toggle();
});
```

Comment: If i click the label, the checkbox will always be checked/unchecked. But I want to be able to toggle without checking/unchecking. Javascript is needed here...

Comment: @JeroenBellemans I don't get why you wouldn't want the checkbox to get checked. Why have the checkbox input at all then?

Comment: the paragraphs are just dummy content. but those are in face all checkboxes. So I could hide them all using the toggle, or check them all using the checkbox ;)